# Echo command cuts new lines

Tags: bash, echo, command-prompt, prompt, cat

I'm trying this command in my prompt to get all results into one file:

```
$ echo $(apt-cache search nano) > search
```

But, they are writing in a one line:

```
$ cat search
alpine-pico - Simple text editor from Alpine, a text-based email client libboost-chrono-dev - C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks (default version) libboost-chrono1.49-dev - C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks libboost-chrono1.49.0 - C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks science-config - Debian Science Project config package science-nanoscale-physics - Debian Science Nanoscale Physics packages science-nanoscale-physics-...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo -e "$(apt-cache search nano)" > search`

Comment: @TomFenech write it as an answer, so I could mark it as right! thx

Comment: It solves the problem but [as anubhava rightly points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480817/2088135), it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use:

```
apt-cache search nano > search
```

There is no need to use `echo` and command substitution which is stripping newlines to a space due to absence of quotes around your command.